# How to use C++/C# code to control skype on PC?

Tags: c#, uri, desktop-application, skype, skype-uri.js

I searched on the interest, it said the Skype4com already stopped working in 2014, and only Skype URIs are official supported.

However, Skype URIs seems only support web browser.

Is there anyway to control Skype in C++/C# on PC?

Comment: your best option to use Skype in a c++ program is to download a light weight JavaScript library for cross platform use, or make a windows 8, 8.1, or 10 app and use the JavaScript API's supplied by Microsoft in the Windows Run Time, this is how i use Skype in my c++ programs because using Skype SecureDevelopers way doesn't actually allow you to control Skype it simply starts the Skype process through terminal, hope you get your app working best of lucks (=

Answer (score -1):

Use this in C#,

```
ProcessStartInfo PInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
PInfo.Domain = "Domain";
PInfo.UserName = "YourUserName";
PInfo.Password = "YourPassword";
PInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe";
PInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Process skype = Process.Start(PInfo);
```

here Change `@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe"` to directory where your skype is installed, and other parameters as well,

Comment: Now you can controll by variable `skype` in your code,

Comment: What can I do then if I want to make a call to a certain person with a audio stream？

Comment: Any chance you can publish an example for c++?